# How to Import XML data into Hive using attributes as columns

Tags: xpath, hive, hiveql

I am pretty new with HiveQL and I am kinda stuck :S

I have a data stored in xml format and I want to extract fields from this xml file in a Hive table of columns (string Titles_2 , sting Artists_2, string Albums_2) .

A Sample of the xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MC><SC><S uid="2" gen="" yr="2011" art="Samsung" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music" alb="Samsung" ttl="Over the horizon"/><S uid="37" gen="" yr="2010" art="Jason Derulo" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Jason Derulo/Jason Derulo" alb="Jason Derulo" ttl="Whatcha Say"/><S uid="38" gen="" yr="2010" art="Jason Derulo" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Jason Derulo/Jason Derulo" alb="Jason Derulo" ttl="In My Head"/><S uid="39" gen="" yr="2011" art="Alexandra Stan" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Alexandra Stan/Mr_ Saxobeat - Single" alb="Mr. Saxobeat - Single" ttl="Mr. Saxobeat (Extended Version)"/><S uid="40" gen="" yr="2011" art="Bushido" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Bushido/Jenseits von Gut und Böse (Premium Edition)" alb="Jenseits von Gut und Böse (Premium Edition)" ttl="Wie ein Löwe"/><S uid="41" gen="" yr="2011" art="Bushido" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Bushido/Jenseits von Gut und Böse (Premium Edition)" alb="Jenseits von Gut und Böse (Premium Edition)" ttl="Verreckt"/><S uid="42" gen="" yr="2011" art="Lucenzo" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/Music/Lucenzo/Danza Kuduro (feat_ Don Omar) [From _Fast &amp; Furious 5_] - Single" alb="Danza Kuduro (feat. Don Omar) [From &quot;Fast &amp; Furious 5&quot;] - Single" ttl="Danza Kuduro (feat. Don Omar) [From &quot;Fast &amp; Furious 5&quot;]"/><S uid="121" gen="" yr="701" art="Michael Jackson" cmp="&lt;unknown&gt;" fld="/mnt/sdcard/external_sd/Music/Michael Jackson/Bad [Bonus Tracks]" alb="Bad [Bonus Tracks]" ttl="Voice-Over Intro/Quincy Jones Interview #1 [*]"/></SC><PC/></MC>
```

This data is stored in a table called xmlout_2(line) .

Now I ran these xpath commands to build the HiveQL table Stores but it only adds the first song of each line. Any idea why is it behaving like that?

```
create view xmlout_2(line) as SELECT * from hivetesttable;

    CREATE VIEW Stores(Titles_2,  Artists_2, Albums_2) AS
    SELECT 
    xpath_string ( line, '/MC/SC/*/@ttl'),
    xpath_string (line, 'MC/SC/*/@art'),
    xpath_string (line, '/MC/SC/*/@alb')
    FROM  xmlout_2;
```

if I try xpath instead of xpath_string  I got an array of strings instead of strings.

```
create view xmlout_2(line) as SELECT * from hivetesttable;

    CREATE VIEW Stores(Titles_2,  Artists_2, Albums_2) AS
    SELECT 
    xpath ( line, '/MC/SC/*/@ttl'),
    xpath (line, 'MC/SC/*/@art'),
    xpath (line, '/MC/SC/*/@alb')
    FROM  xmlout_2;
```

I am thinking of exploding the columns after that but exploding can be only used on a single column.